# Put something up on the top shelf or Put something on the top shelf?

Tags: difference

1. Put those books up on the top shelf.
2. Put those books on the top shelf.

> What is the difference in meaning between the first sentence (with
>   **"verb + up on something"** in it) and the second sentence (without "up", just **"verb + on something"** in it)?

I'm wondering whether the adverb "up" is added in the sentence just for emphasis, and if I remove it, the sentence is still understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relevant phrasal verb *put up* (there are some, but not applicable in this context).

So the *up* is indeed an adverb, with its full basic meaning, and would emphasis that the top shelf is high up. It can certainly be omitted.